# Why didn't Alan and Sarah destroy the Jumanji board game?

Tags: jumanji

I just recently watched Jumanji on HBO. Considering what happened in the year 1995, the events were drastically tragic, especially to the main characters. When Alan and Sarah beat the game they were reset back in 1969. Afterward, they decided to throw the game off a bridge into a river down below. At this point, they are both well aware of the consequences of someone finding the board, but they still just throw that sucker back into the water and go about their lives. **Wouldn't it have made sense to destroy it** or at least become sworn protectors and make sure that no one makes the same mistake? As we can see in the ending of the film that two kids are walking on the beach and hearing the drum sounds of Jumanji. You know, I watched this several times when I was a kid but the film is already 25 years old. When I go deep into the movie, I wonder why no one asks or wonders why didn't they just destroy the game considering the damage that had been. Also covered in [cinemablend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2550206/jumanji-things-that-dont-make-sense-about-the-1995-movie).

Comment: There is no official reason stated but The Jumanji Board has displayed a lot of magical power and it would make sense that that magic protects it from any form of destruction. Although never shown in the movie it might be possible they tried and failed to destroy the board, or were afraid that destroying the board would unleash a magical rampage that could not be undone. The reason why they don't sit on it as it's guardians is probably fear motivated... would you want to store a bomb in your house?

Comment: You have kind of answered your own question. Yes, they could have destroyed it but dark and powerful forces exist within it. This means that it’s almost impossible to destroy I would have thought. They would have assumed this, themselves.

Comment: Alan was trapped in the game until 1995, and returned to 1969 after he finally beat it.  Maybe destroying the game in 1969 would create some kind of paradox, if it no longer exists in 1995 for the next generation to "let him out."  They could still sit on it until 1995 I suppose, but like A.bakker says, do you really want to keep something like that in your house?

Comment: As long as we're speculating in comments, the movies show that the game has an ability to influence people to find it and start a game. It may also have the ability to influence them to throw it away when the game is over so other people can find it.

Comment: it is basically a plot hole then

Comment: _"Wouldn't it have made sense [..]?"_ Where is it stipulated that (a) anything that makes sense must invariably be done and (b) teenage Alan and Sarah are making a sensible choice to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

The movie was intended to be open-ended, like the source material.  The children's book it was based on ended with the main characters seeing two neighbors finding the board game and bringing it home.  The movie had many variations from the original story, however.  As the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji_(picture_book)#Adaptations) from the book states:

> Jumanji, a 1995 film based on the story, is an adaptation of the
> picture book. Unlike the short story, the film has adult characters
> that did not appear in the original short story like Alan Parrish
> (Robin Williams/Adam Hann-Byrd), Sarah Whittle (Bonnie Hunt/Laura Bell
> Bundy), Officer Carl Bentley (David Alan Grier), Aunt Nora (Bebe
> Neuwirth) and a big-game hunter named Van Pelt (Jonathan Hyde who also
> portrayed Alan's father, Sam Parrish). Not only is Alan Parrish the
> main protagonist instead of Judy (Kirsten Dunst) and Peter (Bradley
> Pierce), but a background story is added, in which the game trapped
> Alan in the jungle many years earlier while he and Sarah were playing
> back in 1969. Danny and Walter Budwing from the end of the original
> book do not appear in the film. Also in the film, Judy and Peter are
> orphaned after their parents died in a car accident in Canada and
> their aunt is now their legal guardian. Other changes are that the
> animals wreak havoc all over town, Peter transforming into a monkey
> while trying to cheat and Alan ultimately winning the game instead of
> Judy with everything including time restored back to the way it was
> before. The drumbeats in the game are also heard far away, which never
> happened in the book.